# ARMv7 Assembly How to Read value of each bit

Tags: assembly, arm

If I have a register that holds a value, how do I read each bit separately and process it in a way to store whether the bit is a 0 or 1? My understanding is to read the first bit, shift right, read first bit, shift right, and repeat until empty. But I can't figure out how to read the bit. I understand shift is just LSR which is easy.

Comment: `LSRS` puts the bit shifted out into the carry flag. Alternatively, use bitwise `AND` with 1 to isolate the least significant bit.

Comment: Do you just perform AND on the value and another 32 bit value that is all 1s? Wouldn't that just return the original value? I don't know how to isolate the least significant bit - is there an operation for that?

Comment: It's not all ones, only the least significant bit is 1.

Comment: @MikeTero: if you find the answers helpful, you can show it by upvoting (and accepting).

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

You can you a `tst` instruction:

```
tst r0, #4           @ set Z if bit 0x04 is clear in R0
```

You can shift the desired bit out of the register into the carry flag:

```
movs r0, r0, lsr #3  @ set C if bit 0x04 was set in R0
```

You can extract the desired bit into a register on its own:

```
ubfx r1, r0, #2, #1  @ set R1 to 1 if bit 0x04 is set in R0
```

If you want to do this in a loop to process each bit in sequence, using the `C` flag (which you can conditionally execute code on with the `CS` and `CC` condition codes) is probably the best choice.  For example, to count the bits in `R0` you can use code like this:

```
        mov    r1, #0          @ initialise counter to zero
loop:   movs   r0, r0, lsr #1  @ shift R0 to the right and set C to its LSB
        addcs  r1, r1, #1      @ increment R1 if C was set
        bne    loop            @ loop until R0 is clear
```

Comment: I think your code is broken, the `bne` is using the result of the `addcs`. You do not need the `s` there.

Comment: @Jester `addcs` is an `add` conditional on `cs`.  It does not alter flags (if that was desired I would have to use `addscs`).  `adc` works too but I wanted to illustrate the use of the `cs` predicate.

Comment: And if `adc` is used it would have been `adc r1, r1, #0`

Comment: Ah I see, got confused by the `s`.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry for the bad edit, I was thinking of only good way on x86 to add CF to a register (`adc reg,0`) and didn't notice the immediate `#1` instead of `#0` or even think about ARM predicated execution.  I guess that's at least equally good, except maybe in Thumb mode where it takes a separate `it` instruction.  But in Thumb mode, LSR is its own instruction instead of an alias for MOV with a shifted source, so it looks like you're writing for ARM mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes The code actually assembled for both (once you add the missing `it cs` instruction depending on your assembler), but slightly better code is generated if `movs r1, #0` is used in the last example.  The unified assembly language (UAL) is designed such that the same code can be used for ARM and Thumb mode.

Comment: Right, both ways are doable on either mode.  I had been assuming that `adc r1, #0` would be a narrow 2-byte instruction, but it's actually 4 bytes, same as `it` / `add`.  It's still just one instruction, but IDK which would run faster on which real CPUs.  (Does `it` take up a separate decode slot on some / most CPUs?  I'm assuming decoding of 4-byte instructions is at least as efficient as handling `it`/`add`, and that `adc` having 3 inputs (2 regs + C) doesn't make it too much more expensive, unlike on Intel P6-family.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Embedded systems may process `it` and `addcs` as two instructions, but some of them also have a throughput of 1 instruction word per cycle, so `adc r1, #0` would take 2 cycles on them.  On the other hand application-class processors seem to implement the `it` instruction predicating one instruction of a certain set of possible instructions as a prefix with no extra cost.  So I think it comes out to either the same or `adc` being faster.